# Ffmpeg: writing audio and video to a stream in an mpeg format

Tags: c++, audio, video, ffmpeg

I had the commands for exporting a video stream to an mpeg file working correctly with the following code:

```
ffmpeg -r 24 -pix_fmt rgba -s 1280x720 -f rawvideo -y -i -vf vflip -vcodec mpeg1video -qscale 4 -bufsize 500KB -maxrate 5000KB OUTPUT_FILE
```

Now, I wanted to add the commands so that audio can be used as well since there's no option for that right now.

I've edited the previous command to the next one:

```
ffmpeg -r 24 -pix_fmt rgba -s 1280x720 -f rawvideo -y -i -f s16le -ac 1 -ar 44100 -i - -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -b:a 320k -ar 44100 -vf vflip -vcodec mpeg1video -qscale 4 -bufsize 500KB -maxrate 5000KB OUTPUT_FILE
```

So as you can see I added a new input with the settings for the audio I'm going to be inputting (I'm going to test this with the values of a sine wave).

I'm writing the data to the file like this:

```
// Write a frame to the ffmpeg stream
fwrite(frame, sizeof(unsigned char*) * frameWidth * frameHeight, 1, ffmpeg); 

// Write multiple sound samples per written frame
for (int t = 0; t < 44100/24; ++t)
    fwrite(&audio, sizeof(short int), 1, ffmpeg);
```

The first line is the one that only writes the video (where the frame object is a render to texture from the video I'm inputting)
After that I'm trying to add the audio. I'm using a for-loop so I can use multiple samples per video frame (because otherwise you would only have 24 audio samples per second)

This does render with a couple of issues:

- The rendered video shows green flashes
- The video slides across the screen. For example, if it slides 200 pixels to the right those pixels get rendered at the other side. Also a bit of the frame that should be at the bottom is rendered at the top (so the frame also slides down but this is a constant, it doesn't move over time)

I can't figure out where my mistake is. I've tried multiple codecs and tried different orders for the commands but it stays the same or gets worse.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are functions to calculate the frame size for specified format. Use them instead of this weird `sizeof(unsigned char*)`, whatever you meant with that.

Comment: BTW. I don't know where you have found such a way of creating the audio-video stream by writing out the video frame followed by an audio frame and what you're going to achieve with that. The "normal" way of doing this is to use specific "muxer" (ffmpeg provides everything you need) that you would stuff in video frames and audio frames that have assigned appropriate timestamps that you'd keep in sync and the ffmpeg functions will multiplex the stream and write it out automatically.

Comment: Well, that's been used to calculate the total size of the data that's going to be written to the stream. Could you elaborate some more on which functions you mean or where I can find them?

I know there are these muxer things but I thought that they weren't needed if I were to write it out myself (the first line, where the video is written to the file wasn't my code. I'm building upon it)

Comment: I think the fwrite is necessary because the frames get rendered in realtime from no specific stream or device, it's just a rendered texture being put in the file

Comment: For starters, look at  this example: https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/output-example_8c-source.html

The problem is that there must be some way to recognize what you're giving your player to read. Raw video frames have completely no information what it is. If you are seeing any video frames, it meas that you have somehow declared that these are RGBA-formatted video frames with predeclared size - but the player blindly believes that these are only frames. To make player know what's in the bitstream, you need a "media container", which gives it some marks to know what's there.

Comment: Indeed, those frames that are coming in are in RGBA-formatted. So I guess it works without the media container is because there's no audio involved? I'll go through the example you linked

Comment: As you have shown in the code, you're writing the audio, too, just after the video frames...

Comment: I'm sorry, I was unclear. When I didn't try to add the audio it worked just fine. I guess this was because the video frames where properly put right behind each other without any other information. The output didn't have an audio stream and only one input so I guess that's why it worked before. I guess that I'll have to rework the entire thing so that it uses the AVContext things

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to include only the libavformat framework in my project and let is use the static .exe I have from ffmpeg. If this can't be done I need to find another way to do this.

Comment: Technically - yes, it's possible. The only discussive thing may be the license, alghough AFAIK only encoders are on GPL license (not sure about the muxer), decoders are on LGPL license.

The player must somehow know what kind of data it's reading, so there must be some "informational" part in the bitstream. Frames in RGBA or YUV are just pictures, without even known sizes and depth, not even mentioning the framerate. At best you can give player these data, but there's no possibility how to tell it that there's also audio, its parameters, and audio frame length. For that you need the container